Block of characters with no spaces
The puzzle is this string of text:
TDHOCNHKSGHOCLEUTYUEDYRYNPQYWORUNHUYTCTVQAYHWYNGYELATJHCGACWMFLYMUMOVNYQZPAYLYCQIEWG
VVVADIINCIIWAZHIZCJAFJCJPIJAFJELXSUIFMTYWPVSQUUAJYCDFZSNJXRGGUDAMCGTGMRYKLVRALSFZARS
ZRTOVKDBDVVCLRYGIJIOFZODTSLRURUCGIJSMTWMMXYYXGCC-JLPOMGLPZEUYYUTGOXFOTGDFVZVSGSEKJVV
RDEZBBQEUSRZCKSYZWPEYHSOZDHSUZYSMPNLIHEMBKWWHCZEXNYFEFYRHJAWOLWOAYNMQXYYNWYSMDJXHMDY

above the string, there was a list of numbers:
[3]    [4]    [5]    [6]   [13]   [57]   [58]   [60]   [85]   [98]   [107]   [158]   [175]   [179]   [188]   [198]   [202]   [212]   [259]   [276]   [293]   [294]   [323]
The letters D, Q, R, and Y were highlighted in this manner:
TDHOCNHKSGHOCLEUTYUEDYRYNPQYWORUNHUYTCTVQAYHWYNGYELATJHCGACWMFLYMUMOVNYQZPAYLYCQIEWG
VVVADIINCIIWAZHIZCJAFJCJPIJAFJELXSUIFMTYWPVSQUUAJYCDFZSNJXRGGUDAMCGTGMRYKLVRALSFZARS
ZRTOVKDBDVVCLRYGIJIOFZODTSLRURUCGIJSMTWMMXYYXGCC-JLPOMGLPZEUYYUTGOXFOTGDFVZVSGSEKJVV
RDEZBBQEUSRZCKSYZWPEYHSOZDHSUZYSMPNLIHEMBKWWHCZEXNYFEFYRHJAWOLWOAYNMQXYYNWYSMDJXHMDY
My friend made the puzzle, and assured me it can be solved with very little cryptography knowledge. I just need a nudge in the right direction. The answer has 336 characters, including spaces.
What I've tried:

Caesar cipher
Corresponding the numbers in the list to characters in the string, and using those as a key for a Vigenère cipher
brute forcing a substitution cipher
counting the numbers of each letter

ORIGINAL IMAGE:

ADDITIONAL IMAGES TO SHOW HIDDEN MESSAGES:



I have been informed by my friend that they made a mistake when creating the puzzle. instead of highlighting the letters DROY, they highlighted DRQY, as seen in the attached images. the O they intended to be highlighted was the one to the left of the Q that was highlighted, between the S and the Z.

336 characters happens to be the exact length of the third part of the Kryptos cipher.

If there's stuff above the string of letters, and highlighting, and the like, could you please show us an image of the original thing so that we can see it? (Maybe e.g. the positioning of the numbers might be significant, or exactly how the letters are highlighted, or something.)

Also, any context would be relevant. Is this the first puzzle your friend has given you? did they say anything about it or just give you the puzzle out of the blue with no explanation? have you set them puzzles?

try cryptoquip.net solver tool to solve it

(Micke's comment above was originally posted as an answer, I assume because Micke is a new user who doesn't have enough rep to be allowed to post comments yet. I converted it to a comment since it doesn't in any way answer the question.)

I will put the image there, the highlighted letters and the numbers were revealed by increasing/decreasing the brightness of the image, as well as upping or lowering the contrast. This is the first puzzle that this friend has sent me. It was in response to me complaining that the puzzles in a game I was making were too simple, and I was looking for harder ones. This friend has not seen the puzzles in the game, however, so they cannot be related. I have not sent them any puzzles, though we have an in joke of sometimes typing using the NATO alphabet. @garethmccaughan

I can see the highlighting (with an image editor -- it is not in the slightest bit visible to the naked eye, for me) and also slightly lighter regions inside the black "arrows" at top and bottom, but I still don't see the numbers you say were "above the string". What am I missing?

@Gareth McCaughan the numbers are within that lighter area of the arrows. to find them I put the image into photopea and then set the brightness to maximum and the contrast to minimum. Using this same method, there is another message in the bottom arrow that reads "its never as simple as brightening an image, silly goose".

@jasperrice I just did the same as you described and i don't see any integers or a message, just the lighter regions.  I'm worried that when you reuploaded the image to post here the compression caused some of that fine detail to be lost, which might make it impossible for us to solve.

@SQLnoob I will put in an image of the edited image to see the message

Decrypt separately 1st, 2nd and 3rd row with Vignere (use dcode.fr), you'll get from Oh you think ... some more.

That's not exactly what the message at the bottom reads. May I ask whether you and your friend happen to know someone called Vera?

@Garethmccaughan I know the message there, I think it's just a jab at a mutual friend of ours that I don't think is totally relevant to the solution of the puzzle. I have solved the first 3 lines, using the tip from z100, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

The list of numbers (repair it, starts with 3,4,5,6 ...) seems to be a youtube link.

@z100 I'm not sure what you mean by repair, but the list of numbers is too long to be a youtube link.

It is not 2,3,5,6... but 3,4,5,6,13,57,58,60..., relates to "youtube w..." in decrypted txt.

@z100 I'm afraid I still don't understand. thanks for pointing out that I mistyped the list, I must have entered it wrong when writing up the post, but I'm not sure how one would translate the list to letters in the first place, aside from a=1, b=2 and variations of that, which seem to not apply here given that no numbers repeat.

Letters from final text, 2nd, 3rd ... 57th, 58th ... are "youtube watch de oley ...", last 5 letters are from the 4th row, which is still not decoded.
